# Content Security Policy directive

Tags: angular, angular8, content-security-policy, syncfusion

In my project i am using Angular 8 and node 10 version and using Syncfusion package for fowdiagram

> Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:3332/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback

I am getting this error when i do `ng build --prod`

Can someone help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i execute the below command its working as expected

ng build --prod --base-href /anyname

Answer (score 0):

We have checked in our sample and we could not able to replicate an issue at our end. Please share us more details such as modify the below sample.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Angular-Sample738660412

Regards, 
Shyam G